# Accessing multiple arrays in JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, json.net

My JSON looks like this:

```
    {"2013" : [
        { "date":"2013-01-09 12:00:00","height":0 },
        { "date":"2013-01-19 12:00:00","height":3 },
        { "date":"2013-01-29 12:00:00","height":2 }],
    "2012" : [
        { "date":"2012-02-09 12:00:00","height":0 },
        { "date":"2012-02-19 12:00:00","height":4 },
        { "date":"2012-02-29 12:00:00","height":2 }],
    "2011" : [
        { "date":"2011-03-09 12:00:00","height":3 },
        { "date":"2011-03-19 12:00:00","height":8 },
        { "date":"2011-03-29 12:00:00","height":2 }]
   }
```

What I am trying to do is get all of the dates and height, but I am only able to do it per year using this code:

```
    public class Report
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    JObject data = JObject.Parse(sr);
    var postTitles = from p in data["2013"]
                     select new Report
                     {
                         Date = DateTime.Parse((string)p["date"]),
                         Height = (int)p["height"]
                     };
```

I was thinking of using a for loop but trying a variable inside data[" "] won't work.  I was also thinking of doing var postTitles += statement but it is not allowed as well.  Any ideas on how I should go about this?  I am using JSON.NET and it is suggested that I do a class per year (i.e. 2013, 2012, 2011) but I want them under one class to make it easier to manipulate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned and twisted Mark's anwer somewhat and came up with this:

```
var postTitles = data.Children() // Select array container properties, like "2013"
        .SelectMany(x => x.First) // Select each subitem from every array
        .Select(r => // Create a report for each item
            new Report
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse((string)r["date"]),
                    Height = (int)r["height"]
                }
            );
```

Hopefully the inline comments will explain the logic sufficiently.

Comment: It did work.  Thank you!  Building on your question.  The data is actually too large so my app suddenly lags.  Say, If I am going to to choose the first 100 "Reports", will a for loop work?  Because right now, I am using a a foreach (var s in postTitles) loop, using s.Date and s.Height to reference each.  How would I go about it if I change it to for loop?

Comment: @CCCC See Mark's updated answer for solutions to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that great with the LINQ syntax you are using but what you want to do is create a list from many lists. So you want to use the SelectMany mapping operation from LINQ.

```
var postTitles = data.Children()
        .SelectMany(subitems => subitems.First)
        .Select(dataOfYear =>
            new Report
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse((string)dataOfYear ["date"]),
                    Height = (int)dataOfYear ["height"]
                }
            );
```

If you want only the first 100 reports of every year you could do it like this:

```
var postTitles = data.Children()
        .SelectMany(subitems => subitems.First)
        .Take(100)
        .Select(dataOfYear =>
            new Report
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse((string)dataOfYear ["date"]),
                    Height = (int)dataOfYear ["height"]
                }
            );
```

Or if you just want to free up the UI thread you could run this in a background thread:

```
var postTitles = await Task.Run(() => data.Children()
        .SelectMany(subitems => subitems.First)
        .Select(dataOfYear =>
            new Report
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse((string)dataOfYear ["date"]),
                    Height = (int)dataOfYear ["height"]
                }
            ));
```

Comment: Is there something missing after the "dataOfYear =>" statement?

Comment: @CCCC sorry I used another dummy structure for testing, after loading the json data with JSON.Net I came to the same conclusion as PatrikW