# C# Parse Json two dimensional array without format from geobytes.com

Tags: c#, json, geolocation

I use geobytes api to find nearby city

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/GetNearbyCities?&radius=220&limit=3
```

api result is 2 dimension json array without attribute name

```
[
    ["0.00", "Phuket", "PU", "Thailand", "North", "0.00", "TH", "0.00", "7.883000", "THPUPHUK", "98.400002", "0.00", "Phuket"],
    ["35.90", "Surat Thani", "ST", "Thailand", "North-East", "92.72", "TH", "171.72", "9.133000", "THSTSTHA", "99.317001", "106.70", "Surat Thani"]
]
```

How can I get a list of city names from this json result with newtonsoft json  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that valid JSON?

Comment: There are a ton of answers for this quesion here on stackoverflow. Use the search and you'll find a lot. e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587344/accessing-multiple-arrays-in-json-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
     string[][] geobytesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(geobytesResponseString);
     const int cityIndexInCityInfoArray = 1;
     string[] cityNames = geobytesResponse.Select(cityInfoArray => cityInfoArray[cityIndexInCityInfoArray]).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks yar_shukan. this help me a lot.
but 2nd Array can not use Select. Then I try something like this :

 foreach (cityNames[] city in cities)
      {
          nearbyCityList.Add(city[1]);
     }

Comment: @user3338721 what do you mean by 2nd Array can't use .Select? If this helped you, I think the best way you can thank you is upvote and accept this as an answer. thx